# nodejs scope with render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

my code:

```js
app.js

var express = require("express")
var path = require('path')
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var _ = require('underscore')
var Movie = require('./models/movie')
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/imooc_projects')

app.set('views', './views/pages')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')))
app.listen(port)

console.log('imooc started on port ' + port);

//index page
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Movie.fetch(function(err, movies) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }

        res.render('index', {
            title: 'imooc 首页',
            movies: movies
        })
    })
})


//detail page
app.get('/movie/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id

    console.log("putain")
    console.log(id)

    Movie.findById(id, function(err, movie) {

            
        console.log(movie)

        res.render('detail', {
            title: 'imooc' + movie.title,
            movie: movie
        })
    })
})


//admin page
app.get('/admin/movie', function (req, res) {
    res.render('admin', {
        title: 'imooc 后台录入页',
        movie: {
            director: '',
            country: '',
            title: '',
            year: '',
            poster: '',
            language: '',
            flash: '',
            summary: ''
        }
    })
})

// admin update movie
app.get('/admin/update/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id

    if (id) {
        Movie.findById(id, function(err, movie) {
            res.render('admin', {
                title: 'imooc 后台更新页',
                movie: movie
            })
        })
    }
})



//admin post movie
app.post('/admin/movie/new', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.body.movie._id
    var movieObj = req.body.movie
    var _movie


    console.log(id)

    if (id !== undefined) {
        Movie.findById(id, function(err, movie) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            console.log("alkfoaj1")
            _movie = _.extend(movie, movieObj)
            //console.log(movie)
            //console.log(movieObj)
            //console.log(_movie)
            //console.log("alkfoaj2")
            _movie.save(function(err, movie) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            //console.log("alkfoaj3")
                res.redirect('/movie/' + movie._id)
            })
        })
    }
    else {

        console.log("else")
        _movie = new Movie({
            director: movieObj.director,
            title: movieObj.title,
            country: movieObj.country,
            language: movieObj.language,
            year: movieObj.year,
            poster: movieObj.poster,
            summary: movieObj.summary,
            flash: movieObj.flash
        })

        _movie.save(function(err, movie) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }

            //console.log(movie._id + "a")
            res.redirect('/movie/' + movie._id)
        })
    }
})
//list page
app.get('/admin/list', function (req, res) {
    Movie.fetch(function(err, movies) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }

        res.render('list', {
            title: 'imooc 列表页',
            movies: movies
        })
    })
})
```

```js
**movie.js**
var mongoose =require ('mongoose')

var MovieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 director: String,
 title: String,
 language: String,
 country: String,
 summary: String,
 flash: String,
 poster: String,
 year: Number, 
 meta:{
  createAt:{
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now()
  },
  updateAt:{
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now()
  }
    }
})


MovieSchema.pre('save',function(next) {
 if(this.isNew){
  this.meta.createAt = this.meta.updateAt = Date.now();
 }
 else{
  this.meta.updateAt = Date.now()
 }

 next()

 //console.log("aa")
})



MovieSchema.statics = {
 fetch: function(cb){
  return this
   .find({})
   .sort('meta.updateAt')
   .exec(cb)
 },
 findById: function(id, cb){
  //console.log("aaa")
  return this
   .findOne({_id: id})`enter code here`
   .exec(cb)
 }
}

module.exports = MovieSchema
```

enter code here

**admin.jade**

```html
extend ../layout

block content
 .container
  .row
   form.form-horizontal(method="post",action="/admin/movie/new")
    //-input(type="hidden", name="movie[_id]", value="#{movie._id}")
    .form-group
     label.col-sm-2.control-label(for="inputTitle") 电影名字
     .col-sm-10
      input#inputTitle.col-sm-10.form-control(type="text",name="movie[title]",value="#{movie.title}")
    .form-group
     label.col-sm-2.control-label(for="inputDirector") 电影导演
     .col-sm-10
      input#inputDirector.col-sm-10.form-control(type="text",name="movie[director]",value="#{movie.director}")
    .form-group
     label.col-sm-2.control-label(for="inputCountry") 国家
     .col-sm-10
      input#inputCountry.col-sm-10.form-control(type="text",name="movie[country]",value="#{movie.country}")
    .form-group
     label.col-sm-2.control-label(for="inputLanguage") 语种
     .col-sm-10
      input#inputLanguage.col-sm-10.form-control(type="text",name="movie[language]",value="#{movie.language}")
    .form-group
     label.col-sm-2.control-label(for="inputPoster") 海报地址
     .col-sm-10
      input#inputPoster.col-sm-10.form-control(type="text",name="movie[poster]",value="#{movie.poster}")
    .form-group
     label.col-sm-2.control-label(for="inputFlash") 片源地址
     .col-sm-10
      input#inputFlash.col-sm-10.form-control(type="text",name="movie[flash]",value="#{movie.flash}")
    .form-group
     label.col-sm-2.control-label(for="inputYear") 上映年份
     .col-sm-10
      input#inputYear.col-sm-10.form-control(type="text",name="movie[year]",value="#{movie.year}")
    .form-group
     label.col-sm-2.control-label(for="inputSummary") 电影简介
     .col-sm-10
      input#inputSummary.col-sm-10.form-control(type="text",name="movie[summary]",value="#{movie.summary}")
    .form-group
     .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
     button.btn.btn-default(type="submit") 录入
```

I get this error: `TypeError: cannot read property ‘title’ of undefined`.
but when I try to print out the `movie` object, it give me error like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS1lQ.png)

that means:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l4vR.png)

this part runs two times.
that's weird. je sais pas pourquoi

Comment: The variable `movie` is undefined. What do you see when you print out `err`?

Comment: That is not even syntactically valid code. Don't you have `;` somewhere in your code? Also notice that `undefined` in the console, just before the error. That's the `movie` variable. It's unclear where the output before "qb" comes from.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm thinking the qb is from `console.log(id + "b")`. What I'm confused about is how did the `movie` object got printed out in the first place.

Comment: @Griffith: Right, that's why I said "output *before* 'qb'" ;)

Comment: @FelixKling: Totally misread your comment. Apologies!